# Nested attributes with has_many through association creating object twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-api

I have Rails API application with many to many relationship between users and projects though project_memberships table.

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, -> { uniq }, through: :project_memberships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_memberships, allow_destroy: true
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :project_memberships
end

class ProjectMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :project, presence: true
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  expose(:user, attributes: :user_params)

  respond_to :json

  # removed unrelated actions

  def update
    user.update user_params
    respond_with user
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :first_name, :last_name,
      project_memberships_attributes: 
        [:id, :project_id, :membership_starts_at, :_destroy]
    )
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I send a `PUT` request to `http://localhost:3000/users/1` with the following json:

```
{"user":{"project_memberships_attributes":[{"project_id": 1}]}
```

`user.update user_params` creates 2 ProjectMembership records with the same `user_id` and `project_id`.

```
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "project_memberships" ("project_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["project_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-03-18 18:00:07.670012"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-18 18:00:07.670012"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "project_memberships" ("project_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["project_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-03-18 18:00:07.671644"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-18 18:00:07.671644"]]
  (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Btw destroying and updating already existing records by specifying `id` in nested attributes works correctly.

Comment: First thing I would check is if the `config/routes.rb` are properly set so that this is the proper Controller#Action being called.

Comment: @JonathanSoifer I put `binding.pry` before and after `user.update` and execution stopped so I guess routes are correct. And SQL queries I added at the end were called in between.

Answer (score 1):

The first step you need to take is to ensure uniqueness on the database level:

```
class AddUniquenessConstraintToProjectMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # There can be only one!
    add_index :project_memberships, [:user, :project], unique: true
  end
end
```

This avoids race conditions that would occur if we relied on ActiveRecord alone.

[image: (C) Thoughtbot]

From [Thoughtbot: The Perils of Uniqueness Validations](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

You then want to add an application level validation to avoid the ugly DB driver exceptions that occur if you violate the constraint:

```
class ProjectMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :project, presence: true 
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :project_id
end
```

You can then remove the `-> { uniq }` lambda on your associations as you have taken the proper steps to ensure uniqueness.

The rest of your issues are due to a misunderstanding of how `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works:

> For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be
>   instantiated, unless the hash also contains a `_destroy` key that
>   evaluates to true.

So `{"user":{"project_memberships_attributes":[{"project_id": 1}]}` will always create a new record if you do not have proper uniqueness validations.

Comment: If you have an existing DB with data you need to clean out any duplicates before adding the index.

Comment: "will always create a new record" yes I know, that's what I'm expecting here. But it creates not one, but 2 new records instantly and that is the problem. As I said updating and deleting (with id provided) works correctly.

As to the part about database - thanks, really interesting stuff, but it doesn't fix the cause, just its results (blocks second sql insert request on db level).  And I'll need to remove uniqueness constrainst in the future anyway as I want user to be able to be member of a project multiple times (in different time periods).